# Can "dangling" mean "something that won't leave your mind"?

Tags: meaning, usage

Can "dangling" mean "something that won't leave your mind"? One of the definition is:  2. to hang around or follow a person, as if seeking favor or attention. So if the thing follows a person, then I thought it could mean "something that a person obsess over", but looking at the synonyms, I am not sure you can really use it to mean that.

For example:

> The error he saw in the script was a dangling error that sucked in all
>   his attention.

Comment: No, this *isn't* a common metaphor (though there's no obvious reason for this apart from "established idiomatic usage"). But in your example, a ***nagging problem*** would be far more likely (imho it's a bit stylistically weak to repeat the word ***error*** here).

Comment: We do idiomatically ***dangle carrots*** and other "desirable" things by way of inducement (persuasive bribery), but "something that dangles = something that demands attention"  rarely occurs outside the specific *grammatical* context of a [***dangling participle***](https://www.english-grammar-revolution.com/dangling-participle.html) - which is closer to the *literal* sense of ***hanging down, not properly attached***.

Comment: In the example sentence, it would *not* be taken to mean an error that won't leave your mind. The response to the sentence would be *What's a dangling error?* (It sounds as if, like typos and other mistakes, *dangling* is being used to describe a particular category of mistake.)